# AWS S3 Image Uploader with NodeJS and s3-uploader module

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, npm

I am trying to use this module `https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-uploader` but for me it's not clear how to implement it. How to do a `POST` to my router ?

```
.post('/upload', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res, next) => {

let files = req.files;

let client = new Upload(process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME, {
  aws: {
    path: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_PATH,
    region: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_REGION,
    acl: 'public-read'
  },

  cleanup: {
    versions: true,
    original: false
  },

  original: {
    awsImageAcl: 'private'
  },

  versions: [{
    maxHeight: 1040,
    maxWidth: 1040,
    format: 'jpg',
    suffix: '-large',
    quality: 80,
    awsImageExpires: 31536000,
    awsImageMaxAge: 31536000
  },{
    maxWidth: 780,
    aspect: '3:2!h',
    suffix: '-medium'
  },{
    maxWidth: 320,
    aspect: '16:9!h',
    suffix: '-small'
  },{
    maxHeight: 100,
    aspect: '1:1',
    format: 'png',
    suffix: '-thumb1'
  },{
    maxHeight: 250,
    maxWidth: 250,
    aspect: '1:1',
    suffix: '-thumb2'
  }]
});

client.upload(files.file.path, {}, function(err, versions, meta) {
  if (err) { throw err; }

  versions.forEach(function(image) {
    console.log(image.width, image.height, image.url);
    // 1024 760 https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/path/110ec58a-a0f2-4ac4-8393-c866d813b8d1.jpg
  });
});
}
```

inside the `.post` I copied and paste the code they have in NPM website and changed the variables values to mine values.

I am getting this error:

```
Error: Command failed: identify -format "name=
size=%[size]
format=%m
colorspace=%[colorspace]
height=%[height]
width=%[width]
orientation=%[orientation]
" /images/logo.png
/bin/sh: identify: command not found

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:206:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:334:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:498:12)
```

I found a related but not fully helpful topic in this thread:
[Node.js S3-uploader issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39927761/node-js-s3-uploader-issue)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the solution:**

The only thing that I did was installing imagemagick on my localhost.

You have to run this in your terminal.

`cd $HOME`

`brew install imagemagick`

When it finish you can run this to see the version and details

`brew info imagemagick`

If you dont have `brew` then you need to install it.

Thank you